# why rewrite giving us error 403 forbidden

Tags: url-rewriting, http-status-code-403

everything is fine but my product page giving me error 403 forbidden

```
what is issue with my rewrite rule?
```

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9a-zA-Z\-\s]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-\s]+)$ product.php?m=$1&=$2[NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

this was the issue with the update version of Apace 2.4.
URL is space was the issue of the error

i just add **B Flag** in rewriterule and everything is working fine now

this is code after **B Flag**

RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9a-zA-Z-\s]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-\s]+)$ product.php?m=$1&=$2[NC,L,B]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]